# Switch case algorithm Java Problem (Need a new while loop?)

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, switch-statement

I'm trying to run a switch statement based on my array values.

I need to make a while loop, running through my whole array, 
where if the  array bit `value = 0` I need it to run `case 0` 
and if the bit `value = 1` I need it to run `case 1`

I need to run the while loop until it has finished running through the array values and corresponding case switch function

The code I'm working on:

```
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What position do you want the top card to be moved to?");
        System.out.println("Enter \"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\" or \"5\"");
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        int in = i -1;
        //System.out.println(i);
        String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(in);
        System.out.println(binaryString);
        int foo = Integer.parseInt(binaryString, 2);
        System.out.println(foo);

        String[] array = binaryString.split("\\|", -1);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));


            switch (foo) {
            case 0:
            cardForceOutShuffle();
            index = 51;
            break;
            case 1:
            cardForceInShuffle();
            index = 51;
            break;
            }
```

Please help.

Comment: there is no loop in this code

Comment: @jhamon, I know. I need help making a new one to help resolve my problem, i think?

Comment: What do you mean by "index"? Do you want switch(in) to be switch(array[51]) if any of those cases happens?

Comment: What do you intend to do with that binary string stuff? You're converting a number between 0 and 4 (assuming the user follows your instructions :) to binary and then try to split at `|` which isn't in those strings - and you're not using that `array` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **A LOT** of things, this is what I came up with. Please be more precise with your questions..

I added my opinion as comments to some of the code.

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What position do you want the top card to be moved to?");
System.out.println("Enter \"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\" or \"5\"");
int i = scan.nextInt(); // This can lead to an InputMismatchException. Try to check if your input is an integer before you proceed.
int in = i - 1; // Unnecessary

String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(in); // Use i-1 directly
char[] charArray = binaryString.toCharArray(); // Since you need each bit you dont need String.split. Just convert to char[]

for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++) {
    switch (charArray[j]) { // This switch is actually useless, since both cases do the same thing.
    case '0':
        cardForceOutShuffle();
        index = 51; // What is index?
        break;
    case '1':
        cardForceOutShuffle();
        index = 51;
        break;
    }
}
scan.close(); // Close your resources if they are not needed anymore.
```